# Patio cement floor water seepage

Tags: water, concrete

16 year old enclosed patio cement floor with water seepage. No cracks in floor recently started. Only happens when it rains or melting snow. Can I apply a sealer to concrete floor after it completely dries to prevent it from happening?

Answer (score 1):

If the water is coming up though the floor, then a sealer would not last long, might stop it once or maybe two times.

Best solution is usually to find where the water is coming from and then add drain pipes(French drains in the ground around) to move it away.

Sealer can then be used.  Sealers are to stop water from getting into the floor from above, like when a big bucket is dumped on it or rain.